# C Code to convert from sign magnitude to two's complement using restricted operators

Tags: c, bit

I am writing a code in C to convert from sign magnitude to two's compliment. The most significant bit is the sign bit and the input will be a short type.

thus far I have a code that is failing the test (I do not have test cases):

```
int magtoComp(int x) {
int mask = x >> 15;
int mag = x & ~(1 << 15);
return (mag ^ mask) + ~mask + 1;
```

Comment: "*you are not allowed to use big constants such as 0xffffffff*" Is applying the equation `(~0) - (x ^ (1 << 15)) + 1` when the value is negative allowed? It *technically* doesn't use any "big constants".

Comment: The input should be unsigned if you want to use bit operations portably.

Comment: No that would not be allowed because you are using the - operator

Comment: How many bits is the signed-mag input? You appear to use16, but then again, you said your solution fails. Is it supposed to be 16, or the same size an `int`?

Comment: Are you allowed to use `-`? Are you allowed to use `if` `else`?

Comment: [mcve] please! Also, without an error or even usable code, it's really hard to help!

Answer (score 3):

To compute `-x` in two's complement representation, one performs `~x + 1`. if `sign` is the sign bit, this can be written `(x ^ -sign) + sign`. `-` is not allowed but you can compute `-sign` as `~sign + 1`.

Hence this solution:

```
// convert a 16-bit sign+magnitude representation to 2's complement
int shortSignMag2TwosComp(int x) {
    unsigned y = x;                     // use unsigned arithmetics
    unsigned sign = y >> 15;            // extract the sign bit
    unsigned mag = y & ~(1u << 15);      // mask off the sign bit
    return (mag ^ (~sign + 1)) + sign;
}
```

If `int` has more than 16 bits, you can use `int` in place of `unsigned` to conform to the rules:

```
// convert a 16-bit sign+magnitude representation to 2's complement
// assuming type int has more than 15 value bits
int shortSignMag2TwosComp(int x) {
    int sign = x >> 15;            // extract the sign bit
    int mag = x & ~(1 << 15);      // mask off the sign bit
    return (mag ^ (~sign + 1)) + sign;
}
```

Comment: The function is int shortSignMag2TwosComp(int x) {

We cannot change it to unsigned short or change the parameter.

Comment: @MikeJay_CodingJav: OK, answer updated. Should work with `int` of any size.

Comment: [Fully tested](https://godbolt.org/z/8jrxrn5ds)

Comment: The code has some other rules that were revealed when I tested to ensure it meets all the requirements, here is what I got:



c:333:shortSignMag2TwosComp: Illegal data type: unsigned
c:334:shortSignMag2TwosComp: Illegal data type: unsigned
c:335:shortSignMag2TwosComp: Illegal data type: unsigned
c:335:shortSignMag2TwosComp: Illegal constant type (1u)



Is there any way around this?

Comment: @MikeJay_CodingJav: answer amended with extra rules. Note however that `int` is assumed to have at least 16 value bits in addition to the sign bit.

Comment: chqrlie, Nicely done.  Now how to do it, with compliant code, with 16-bit (or wider) `int` (aside from `shortSignMag2TwosComp(INT_MIN)` and assuming 2's comp. encoding?  That would certainly be worth +50.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your computer is 2's complement, it's as easy as:

```
uint32_t sign = data & (1u << 31);
if(sign)
{
  data &= ~(1u << 31);
  data *= -1;
}
```

Or if you will, a slightly more optimized version:

```
int32_t signmag_to_2compl (uint32_t signmag)
{
  int32_t sign = (signmag & (1u << 31)) ? -1 : 1;
  signmag &= ~(1u << 31);    
  return sign * signmag;
}
```

`uint32_t` since it's completely senseless to store a signed magnitude number in an `int` while running on a 2's complement machine. We also want to avoid doing bitwise arithmetic on signed numbers.